# Can't change EditText attributes when tap on buttons

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have an app that shoud change `textSize` and `textStyle` in my `EditText` when I tap on buttons, all runs fine, but no reaction when I tap on buttons.

[Screenshot of running app.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQV8z.png)

I'm using `TableLayout`.

my Layout XML:

https://codebeautify.org/xmlviewer/cb7616d1

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_actyvity);
    }
}
```

MyActyvity.java

```
package com.example.groot.lischuk_6;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MyActyvity extends Activity {
    private float mTextSize=14;
    private EditText mEdit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_actyvity);
        mEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
        final Button buttonR = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_r);
        final Button buttonB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_b);
        final Button buttonI = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_i);
        final Button buttonPlus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_plus);
        final Button buttonMinus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_minus);

        buttonPlus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                float size = mEdit.getTextSize();
                size++;
                mEdit.setTextSize(size);
            }
        });
        buttonMinus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                float size = mEdit.getTextSize();
                size--;
                mEdit.setTextSize(size);
            }
        });
        buttonB.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mEdit.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            }
        });
        buttonR.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mEdit.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
            }
        });
        buttonI.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mEdit.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Project created in Android Studio

VirtualDevice: Nexus 4 API P

Comment: Can you also post `my_actyvity` layout file as well

Comment: Also please add the imports in Myactyvity.java

Comment: you have add that in the question...edit the question and add them

Comment: I added link on my xml, editor does not allow to add into question.

Answer (score 0):

I write code from `MyActyvity.java` inside `MainActyvity.java` and buttons start working.

But I still dont understend how to do it from MyActyvity.java